# how do i count down from 4 and stop at 0 in assembler

Tags: assembly, arm

how do i count down from 4 and stop at 0 in assembler. I have tried this so far. I would like the text to be displayed then 3210. However It prints 3333333333333.
I am trying to store the new result after the subtraction using STR then using the new number subtract 1 again. But it seems to be using 4 all the time.

```
        B main

    verses  DEFW    4
    temp    DEFW    0
    text    DEFB    " men went to mow a meadow ",0

        ALIGN

main    ADR R0,verses
        SWI 4

        ADR R0,text
        SWI 3



loop    ADR R0,verses
        SUB R0,R0,#1
        STR R0,verses
        SWI 4

        B loop



        SWI 2
```

[image]

Comment: What assembler are you using?

Comment: I suspect Komodo, but the OP should specify the target environment in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
ADR R0,verses
```

`SWI 4` expects the *value* to print in `R0`, not the *address of* the value. So, you should use something like `LDR R0,verses` instead. The reason you get 4 when you do `ADR R0,verses` is because `verses` just happens to be located at address 4. But by using `ADR` you'll get 4 whatever you store *at* `verses`.

Also, your `loop` is infinite because you haven't added any code that ever exits the loop. It ought to look something like this instead:

```
LDR R0, verses
loop    SUBS R0,R0,#1
        BMI done
        SWI 4
        B loop
done
```

Note: I don't know if the `SWI`s preserve the value of `R0`. If they don't you'll have to take care of that yourself, e.g. by saving `R0` on the stack.